# Python: Palindrome Integer Composition

Tags: python

This challenge is for codewars:

Given an input n, find the count of all the numbers less than n that are both palindromic and can be written as the sum of consecutive squares.

My idea was to compute the square of incrementing numbers, add the square to the total of previous squares, and test if the total, together with the total minus all previous totals (kept in a list), are palindromes. When the total equals or exceeds n, totals are removed from the beginning of the list until the current total minus the list element is less than n, and the square incrementing is resumed until there is only 1 element remaining in the list.

```
def values(n):
    
    def isPal(n):
        n = str(n)
        if len(n) in [0,1]:
            return True
        return n[0] == n[-1] and isPal(n[1:-1])    
                
    pcount = 0
    current = 2
    totals = [1]
    while True:
        tot = current**2 + totals[-1]
        totals = [e for e in totals if tot - e < n]
        if len(totals) == 1 and totals != [1]: 
            break
        for e in totals[:-1]:
            if isPal(tot - e):
                pcount += 1
        if isPal(tot):
            pcount+=1
        totals.append(tot)
        current += 1
    return pcount
```

My code returns the correct result for n = 100, 200, 300, 400, 1000. For larger n, however, my result is off, mostly by +1, but sometimes +2. I tried substituting a palindrome finder that uses logs rather than converting into a string, but my results are still wrong for larger n.

I know there are other posts on this problem with solutions using Counter and other methods. I'm interested in learning why my code is buggy.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a correct answer for a very large value of N?

Comment: Here's an easy string palindrome check:  `if x==x[::-1]:` (compare string to reversed string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahah, spotted it. Some values can be made in more than one way. 554455 is the smallest value with this property, which is why your functions goes over on big numbers. Rather than having a counter, just make a set to hold all answers found, and return the length of that set.

You're doing good coding - so keep going Mikey!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you got your answer. For performance reasons, I would change the `isPal` function as below:

```
def isPal(n):
    n = str(n)
    return n == n[::-1]
```

Good solution tho!

Comment: Nifty - I will use that instead.